# NUnit Test For Setting Position C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, tdd

So I'm creating a Snake-game and want to test that the "Snake-food" changes `Position` when "eaten".

So I have a simple Position-class that looks kinda like this:

```
public class Position
    {
        public int XCoordinate {get; set;}
        public int YCoordinate {get; set;}

        public Position(int x, int y)
        {
            XCoordinate = x;
            YCoordinate = y;
        }
     }
```

And in the test, I want to see that the Position of the food updates when eaten. Because there seems to be no good way of comparing objects, I'm doing this with Assert like this(simplified method):

```
    [Test]
    public void AssertFoodSpawnsOnNewLocationWhenEaten()
    {
        int expectedX = _sut.Food.Pos.XCoordinate;
        int expectedY = _sut.Food.Pos.YCoordinate;

        _sut.FeedSnake();
        int resultX = _sut.Food.Pos.XCoordinate;
        int resultY = _sut.Food.Pos.YCoordinate;

        Assert.AreNotEqual(expectedX, resultX);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(expectedY, resultY);
    }
```

Realized that my solution is a bad one, since the Food-Position could have been updated even tough e.g. `expectedX` and `resultX`are equal.

Does anyone have a tip how I could test this? Can you do some kind of `Assert.AreNotEqual` checking if both x-and y-coordinates are not equal?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: "Because there seems to be no good way of comparing objects" Sure, there *is* one: overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` within your `Position`-class. This enables you to use `Assert.AreEqual(expected, myInstanceOfPosition)`. Apart from this we don´t know how to test something when you allready say it may change even when `expectedX` and `resultX` are equal.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. The Food-object gets a randomly generated Position. I meant that the new position for the food-object could still have the same x-coord but the y-coord could be different.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Could you give an example of the way of comparing objects?

Comment: Well, if I understand you correctly, you allready determined that your member doesn´t work right, so your test seems bit obsolete to me as it doesn´t unveil any news. So what exactly is your question about? Creating random numbers without duplicate positions?

Comment: @Jesper this looks like a design issue. You may need to rethink how you designed Position.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The test is really to see if the method FeedSnake() updates the position of the Food-object, and I want to check that the Food-object doesn't have the same position, but yeah maybe you're right with the design issue

Comment: @Jesper is `FoodPos` static?

Comment: In this case: what´s the problem? Does the test return false positives or negatives?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (no pun intended)

Comment: I posted an answer on solution, but was kinda hoping that there was a method using NUnit that could provide a way for me to do the IsPositionEqual()-method

Comment: So your entire question was about determing if two objects - in your case two positions - are equal? Just google for this and you´ll soon find your actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Made a separate private function that determines if the x and y coordinates are the same. This checks if `_sut.FeedSnake()`updates the Food-position when eaten.

```
[Test]
public void AssertFoodSpawnsOnNewLocationWhenEaten()
{
    Position expected = _sut.Food.Pos;

    _sut.FeedSnake();
    Position result = _sut.Food.Pos;

    Assert.False(IsPositionEqual(expected, result));
}

private bool IsPositionEqual(Position Pos1, Position Pos2)
{
    if (Pos1.XCoordinate == Pos2.XCoordinate &&
        Pos1.YCoordinate == Pos2.YCoordinate)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```